# Group report Subtotalling

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

[Demo Link](http://aspnettuts.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/asp-net-repeater-group-recordsdata-delete-selected-rows/#comments)

```
<asp:Repeater ID=”Repeater1″ runat=”server”
onitemdatabound=”Repeater1_ItemDataBound”>
<HeaderTemplate><table></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<%# this.RenderGroup(Eval(“ticker_name”) as string)%>
<tr>
<td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, “emp_id”) %></td>

<td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, “emp_name”) %></td>
<td> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, “display_id”) %></td>
<td>
<asp:CheckBox ID=”CheckBox1″ runat=”server” internalid=’<%# Eval(“emp_id”) %>’/></td>
</tr></ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

c#

```
string lastGroup = string.Empty;
protected string RenderGroup(string Group)
{
if (Group == this.lastGroup)
return “”;
else
{
this.lastGroup = Group;
return “<tr class=’groupheader’><td colspan=4>” + Group + “</td></tr>”;
}
```

}

See from the above website i have to show SubTotal.
Like Ticker 1 have 3 record
Ticker 2 have 2 record

```
Ticker 1, Total 03
-------data----------
-------data----------
-------data----------
Ticker 2, Total 02
-------data----------
-------data----------
```

How can i do using in repeater.